# Find the details against on double clicking a particular key

Tags: vba, excel

Can you please help me with this problem?

I want to write a VBA program where when I click on a particular key in sheet1 it goes to the database and find me the details associated with the particular key.

Database is Excel sheet named PSN.

I have written my code below what is wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("E")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True

    Worksheets("PSN").Activate

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("A1:A10000").Find(Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "What is wrong"? You tell us...

Comment: it still does not point to the correct value in the PSN database

Comment: Your code doesn't really do anything though. What should happen if it finds the value?

Answer (score 0):

just mention the sheets to search in.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As 
Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("E")) Is Nothing Then
       Cancel = True
       Dim cell As Range
   Set cell = sheets("PSN").Range("A1:A10000").Find(Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: It is still not pointing to the correct cell in the PSN sheet.

Comment: I want the program to point to the correct cell, can you please help

Comment: Should we activate the value in the cell variable

Comment: Try adding `cell.Select`.

Comment: cell contains the reference to the range object corresponding to the result of the find instruction. You can use its property like .value, .address or method like .select to select this particular cell as mentioned by Ralph.